# How do I install htop in mac OS X?

Tags: software-installation, macos, htop

How do I install [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/) for macOS (OS X)? (The easiest and laziest path)

Comment: Install Linux in a vm. It's a Linux program which uses Linux-specific kernel features, such as the `proc` filesystem.

Comment: No, it has to run natively, it should since htop does works in unix.

Comment: It won't run natively. It's not portable to other *nix OSes for the same reason `procps` is not portable.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Here is the laziest way (or homebrew way)

First install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) if you haven't

Second `brew install htop`

Third, done

Comment: This no longer seems to work: `Error: No available formula or cask with the name "htop".`

Comment: @muad-dweeb https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/htop it should still work. Which macOS version you're on? and have you done `brew update` first?

Comment: Turns out my `brew` was in a bad state. `git -C $(brew --repository homebrew/core) checkout master` solved my issue. I am now able to install `htop`. Cheers!

Answer (score 11):

I installed `htop` 0.8 (update: now 2.0.1) from [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) with

```
sudo port install htop
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Pre-built binary

Found [this tutorial](http://themainframe.ca/2011/06/install-htop-on-mac-os-x/) that shows how to do it. The steps are as follows:

```
$ curl -O http://themainframe.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/htop.zip
$ unzip htop.zip
$ sudo mv htop /bin
$ rm htop.zip
```

This binary is already pre-built so you should use caution when using executables such as this to make sure that they aren't malicious.

#### Building it from scratch

You can also follow these directions if you'd like to attempt to build the executable yourself. The tutorial is called: <strike>[htop for Snow Leopard](http://jeetworks.org/node/60)</strike>. A copy of the original reference material is here on [Tech Chutney](http://shubhamgoel.info/?p=185).

#### General steps

```
$ git clone git://github.com/AndyA/htop-osx.git
```

Building this under Snow Leopard requires you to checkout the 'osx' branch:

```
$ cd htop-osx
$ git checkout -b osx origin/osx
```

and set your 'CFLAGS' environmental variable to specify a 32-bit build:

```
$ export CFLAGS="-m32"
before the actual build:

$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

Comment: The “building from scratch” option is missing the step where one must actually go into the “htop-osx” before doing anything else.

Comment: @JakeGould - sorry I thought that was obvious from having to run the script, `./autogen.sh` since it's inside that directory. I'll add it.

Comment: So look at your edits again.  Now look at this line `git checkout -b osx origin/osx`.  How can anyone do that checkout when they are not in the directory?  The `cd htop-osx` should happen right after the clone. All other actions happen in that directory./

Comment: @JakeGould - Thanks I see what you mean now. In the future you can edit mistakes such as this, BTW.

Comment: @JakeGould - the link is now broken I referenced but the directions were copied from a blog post so that would explain why they were incorrect. I don't own a Mac system so am unable to confirm these A's when I provide them.

Comment: @JakeGould - A reference to the original website: http://shubhamgoel.info/?p=185. Steps were missing from there. I've included this in the A now, thanks for alerting me to all this!

Comment: Unfortunately this is an older version of htop (0.8.2.1) whereas the latest version is 1.0.2 and some functionality (filtering) is missing. It's easy to build from the canonical tarball if you have a recent enough (>= 2.65) version of autoconf.

Answer (score 1):

For the latest version of`htop`: https://htop.dev/